# Prolem with for loop function

Tags: php, foreach

I'm having problem displaying my post.

running:

- Apache ver. 2.2.19 (Unix)
- PHP version   5.2.*

**Error displayed:** "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING index.php on line 22"

Below is the php script:

```
<?php
include('includes/connect_to_mysql.php');   
?>
<?php include_once('functions/functions.php');?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>magazin</title>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>


<?php 


$posts = get_posts(); 

?>


<?php 

foreach( $posts as $post){

  <article>

       <div class="three columns alpha thumbnail">

               <figure><img src="images/<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?>" /></figure>

     </div><!--three-->

          <div class="seven columns omega">

           <h2><a href = "single.php?id=<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?></a></h2>

              <p class="meta">Posted by<a href = "<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_user`]; ?><?php echo $total_comments; ?></a></p>

           <p><?php echo $post[`contents`]; ?></p>
    </div><!--seven--><hr/>

 </article><!--blog post-->

    }
<?php 
  } 
  ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have no syntax error?

Comment: cant you look at your code first, and then ask such question ??

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $posts as $post){

  <article>
```

The issue is here.

You can't use HTML inside PHP like this.

So fix it by doing:

```
foreach( $posts as $post) { ?>

<article>
```

and reopen PHP tag when necessary.

Another alternative is using quotes on your HTML:

```
foreach( $posts as $post) {

   echo '<article>';
```

Comment: yeah you just need to add a closing php tag here

Comment: This won't solve it solely as there is still a missing PHP opening tag after `</article>`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere He learnt how to deal with this issue. I'm sure he'll be able to fix the rest on his own. :)

Comment: And as a second note: Your alternative isn't going to work without `print` or `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't output HTML directly within PHP without echo'ing or printing it out. This suggests you probably need to read more about the basics of PHP. You probably meant this structure:

```
<?php if (something) { ?>

<div>html output here</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `?>` before `<article>`

Here is the corrected code:
You forgot to close the `?>` before `<article>`

Here is the corrected code:

```
    <?php
    include('includes/connect_to_mysql.php');   
    ?>
    <?php include_once('functions/functions.php');?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>magazin</title>
    <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    </head>

    <body>


    <?php 


    $posts = get_posts(); 

    ?>


    <?php 

    foreach( $posts as $post){
// HERE PHP tag wasn't closed.    
?>
      <article>

           <div class="three columns alpha thumbnail">

                   <figure><img src="images/<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?>" /></figure>

         </div><!--three-->

              <div class="seven columns omega">

               <h2><a href = "single.php?id=<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?></a></h2>

                  <p class="meta">Posted by<a href = "<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_user`]; ?><?php echo $total_comments; ?></a></p>

               <p><?php echo $post[`contents`]; ?></p>
        </div><!--seven--><hr/>

     </article><!--blog post-->
    <?php
        }
    <?php 
      } 
      ?> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose php tag after `foreach( $posts as $post){`

Answer (score 0):

You must close php tag when you use html code 
like that

The line after foreach line " ?> "

```
<?php 

    foreach( $posts as $post){
    ?>

      <article>

           <div class="three columns alpha thumbnail">

                   <figure><img src="images/<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?>" /></figure>

         </div><!--three-->

              <div class="seven columns omega">

               <h2><a href = "single.php?id=<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_title`]; ?></a></h2>

                  <p class="meta">Posted by<a href = "<?php echo $post[`posts_id`]; ?>"><?php echo $post[`posts_user`]; ?><?php echo $total_comments; ?></a></p>

               <p><?php echo $post[`contents`]; ?></p>
        </div><!--seven--><hr/>

     </article><!--blog post-->


    <?php 
      } 
      ?>
```